# Kendo grid inline editing removes my drop down list current value

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

Hope someone can help me out with this, as I've spent the past two days trying to figure it out without much success.

Problem: I have a Kendo grid that uses inline editing with a drop down list. When I select the drop down I get my items and when I update the values get set - All Good! However when I initially edit the item the current value that was shown in the grid disappears from the drop down box (if i don't update that field the value still remains the same - just doesn't appear when editing).

My code:

```
schema: {
    model: {
       id: "Id",
       fields: {
          Id: { type: "number" },
          ...
          Relationship: { type: "string" },
          ...
       }
    }
 }


columns: 
[
  { field: "Firstname", title: "Firstname" },
  ....
  { field: "RelationValue", title: "Relationship", editor: GetRelationships, 
  template: function (data) { return "<span title='" + data.Relationship + "'>" 
  + data.Relationship + "</span>" } },
  ...
  { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "110px" }
],
editable: "inline"




function GetRelationships(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="RelationValue" data-value-field="RelationId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "RelationValue",
                dataValueField: "RelationId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            url: "http://localhost:55719//HouseholdMembers/_GetRelationships",
                        }
                    }
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
                    options.model.set("Relationship", dataItem.RelationValue);
                }
            });
    }
```

List Layout for Drop Down

```
public JsonResult _GetRelationships()
{
    List<Relations> Relationships = new List<Relations>();
    Relationships.Add(new Relations() { RelationId = 1, RelationValue = "Partner" });

    return this.Jsonp(Relationships);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please make a dojo for this.

Comment: Not sure what dojo is? I would try and replicate with an online working example, but not sure how as i grab my data and crus actions from a mvc controller

Comment: Just do it with some mock data. I.e. you can edit this example http://dojo.telerik.com/UgaDaP

Comment: Okay, I amended your example with my code and it looks like it illustrate my error

Comment: I have answered your question below. I have tested this in fiddle and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set dropdown value by yourself in your custom editor code. Replace your code `GetRelationships` in your JS script with following code:

```
function GetRelationships(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="RelationValue" data-value-field="RelationId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "RelationValue",
                dataValueField: "RelationId",
                value: options.model.RelationId, // THIS IS THE CHANGE I MADE
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            url: "http://localhost:55719//HouseholdMembers/_GetRelationships",
                        }
                    }
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
                    options.model.set("Relationship", dataItem.RelationValue);
                }
            });
    }
```

For your reference, I have created working DOJO for Grid inline editing with dropdown as editor. You can access that fiddle here [Inline Grid Editing with Dropdown As editor template](http://dojo.telerik.com/UgaDaP/8).

Let me know if this does not work. Otherwise, Please don't forget to mark this as accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help Zeshan, but unfortunately i still cant get it working with 'value'. Could it be that im using a template in my grid column? I had to use this in order to get any values to show that already exist.

Comment: You are right!! The issue was occurring due to template. I have made required adjustment in my answer to make this work with your template. Also update fiddle with required adjustment. http://dojo.telerik.com/UgaDaP/8

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely getting there. I see you've used the parse to enter values into the relation id column and if i use that with local variable for relations it works. If i take the parse out i dont get any values for my relation id.

Comment: exactly!! that thing needs to be in the model.

Comment: Any idea how i can show the text value opposed to the Id ?

Comment: you mean in Grid you want to show text instead of ID?

Comment: That is correct - if i swap id with the text i get the same issue i had before. I cant seem to get the grid to show the text property of the current id for that item (the relation ID that is)

Comment: Just add both text and id property to model. Then show text in grid while for editor you can use id.

Comment: Let me know if this solved your issue. Right now I'm busy will make change to DOJO link later.